# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class biz.tugay.dao.HibernateUtil

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, tomcat, noclassdeffounderror

I am trying to follow [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp) tutorial.

This is my directory structure:

[image]

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>biz.tugay.sakila-jpa</groupId>
    <artifactId>sakila-jpa</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sakila-jpa Maven Webapp</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>sakila-jpa</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Hibernate related files:**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>

        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!--mapping class="biz.tugay.model.Actor"/-->
        <mapping resource="Actor.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping package="biz.tugay.model">

    <class name="Actor" table="actor">
        <id name="actor_id" column="actor_id">
            <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <property name="first_name" type="java.lang.String"/>
        <property name="last_name" type="java.lang.String"/>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Actor class**

```
package biz.tugay.model;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 09:17 */

import java.sql.Timestamp;

public class Actor {

    private Integer actor_id;
    private String first_name;
    private String last_name;
    private Timestamp last_update;

    public Integer getActor_id() {
        return actor_id;
    }

    public void setActor_id(Integer id) {
        this.actor_id = id;
    }

    public String getFirst_name() {
        return first_name;
    }

    public void setFirst_name(String first_name) {
        this.first_name = first_name;
    }

    public String getLast_name() {
        return last_name;
    }

    public void setLast_name(String last_name) {
        this.last_name = last_name;
    }

    public Timestamp getLast_update() {
        return last_update;
    }

    public void setLast_update(Timestamp last_update) {
        this.last_update = last_update;
    }

}
```

**ActorDao**

```
package biz.tugay.dao;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 09:21 */

import biz.tugay.model.Actor;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

import java.util.List;

public class ActorDao {

    public List<Actor> getAll() {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(currentSession);
        return null;
    }

}
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
package biz.tugay.dao;

/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 14:20 */

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory SESSION_FACTORY = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        return new Configuration().configure()
                .buildSessionFactory(new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build());
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return SESSION_FACTORY;
    }

}
```

and finally my Servlet:

```
package biz.tugay.web;
/* User: koray@tugay.biz Date: 06/08/15 Time: 09:31 */

import biz.tugay.dao.ActorDao;
import biz.tugay.model.Actor;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/")
public class WelcomeServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        ActorDao actorDao = new ActorDao();
        List<Actor> actors = actorDao.getAll();
        req.setAttribute("actors",actors);
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp")
                .forward(req,resp);

    }
}
```

When I deploy this application and visit "/" I am getting:

```
06-Aug-2015 14:49:20.119 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [biz.tugay.web.WelcomeServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

06-Aug-2015 14:49:20.130 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [biz.tugay.web.WelcomeServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class biz.tugay.dao.HibernateUtil
    at biz.tugay.dao.ActorDao.getAll(ActorDao.java:13)
    at biz.tugay.web.WelcomeServlet.doGet(WelcomeServlet.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

06-Aug-2015 14:49:20.237 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [biz.tugay.web.WelcomeServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class biz.tugay.dao.HibernateUtil
    at biz.tugay.dao.ActorDao.getAll(ActorDao.java:13)
    at biz.tugay.web.WelcomeServlet.doGet(WelcomeServlet.java:23)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you test your application? Maybe there is some sync-problem between your eclipse and your applicatoin server? Can you deploy your app if you package it with maven?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner I do not use Eclipse. I just create war file with mvn clean install and copy the war file to Tomcat web-apps folder.

Comment: And is the missing class in the jar?

Comment: @MartinBaumgartner Yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are getting an initialization error of the `HibernateUtil` class due to the static `buildSessionFactory` method.

Follow the [Hibernate manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-firstapp-helpers) to implement it in such a way that catch and shows any exception.

I think that maybe related to connection configuration issues in your hibernate configuration file, check the password for example.